# OSX app to paste and save HTML content?

Tags: text-editor, web-browser, websites, html

In Gmail, I can go to a web page, highlight web content, compose a Gmail message, and paste the HTML content into the email message. It works in Mail.app as well.

But what app can I use to just paste the HTML content and then save it as an HTML file?

Microsoft Word will accept pasted HTML content, but I don't want to save as gross weird Microsoft Word HTML markup. Is there an OSX app where I can easily paste and save copied HTML content from web pages?

Answer (score 4):

Although this is an old question, it's still relevant, and here is the answer:

```
pbpaste -Prefer rtf | textutil -stdin -convert html -output outputfile.html
```

This uses the built-in OS X `pbpaste` utility to pipe the contents of the clipboard to stdout (`-Prefer rtf` is probably unnecessary but doesn't hurt), then runs it through the built-in `textutil` program. The `-stdin` argument makes `textutil` take its input from `pbpaste`; `-convert html` tells it to turn the input into HTML; and `-output outputfile.html` tells it to write the output to a file called `outputfile.html`.

If you find that the output has some unnecessary elements, you can exclude them with `-excludedelements`; for example, `-excludedelements '(span, font, head, xml)'`. Note that you need to have the single quotes because your shell will try to interpret the parentheses as a special shell expression.

Comment: A similar answer would be to paste it into a TextEdit "Rich Text" document. You do get some HTML garbage, but it's not bad. Using `textutil` to convert from html to html is clever. I'd tried using `tidy` but it didn't help as much as I thought it would.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just save the page using the browser?

1. File → Save As… (⌘S)

   [image]
2. Choose Page Source or Web Archive

   [image][image]

Comment: because web pages are filled with garbage and ads? there's no reason I would want to save all that content. Also I want to aggregate content from many different web pages.